# Typed.js backspace a text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed.js

I'm trying to use typed.js to have a typing effect on a h1 element. I want to be able to "backspace" the current string in the h1, prior to typing the new element.

```
$(function(){
  $("#hello").typed({
    strings: ["Hello Connor."],
    typeSpeed: 100
  });
});

$('#categories h3').click(function(){
    var string = this.id;
    $("#categories").fadeOut();
    $('#back').fadeIn();
    $("#hello").typed({
    strings: [string + ".", "word"],
    typeSpeed: 100
});
})
```

As you can see, everytime you click on one of the h3 elements in `#categories`, it types out that string in the `#hello` element. I would like it so when you click an h3, it backspaces the current string in the #hello element, and types out the new string

Comment: Did you find a solution?